# Ubuntu Live freezes after seconds

Tags: 18.04, live-usb

I had Ubuntu 14 running for months and everything was working fine until some automatic package upgrades made my laptop inoperable.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18 now, but trying ubuntu live from the USB freezes everything after some seconds. Similarly, I cannot install Ubuntu because the install process freezes. The Ubuntu USB works fine as I just used it to succesfully install it in another laptop.

How can I start debugging this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had to turn off in the bios the hyperthreading and multiprocessor until the installation was done.